# How to know if X-Pack is installed in Elasticsearch?

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-x-pack

I install Elasticsearch with Debian package and installed X-pack in it.
Now, I want to verify if X-Pack is successfully installed.

Is there a simple way to do verify this?

Comment: Maybe this help you https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.2/listing-removing.html

Answer (score 10):

You can call

```
GET _cat/plugins?v
```

Answer (score 1):

xpack comes pre-installed from ElasticSearch `6.3` onwards. Refer to : https://www.elastic.co/what-is/open-x-pack for more info on this.

You can check if xpack is installed using: `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes'`

The relevant output snippet looks like below:

```
"attributes": {
                "ml.machine_memory": "67447586816",
                "xpack.installed": "true",
                "transform.node": "true",
                "ml.max_open_jobs": "512",
                "ml.max_jvm_size": "27917287424"
            }
```